# Assertion failed: check for file existence

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I already follow the MAVROS install tutorial in there:

https://dev.px4.io/en/ros/mavros_installation.html

When I type command `$catkin build` ,

I get cmake error like follow:

```
Errors <<   image_transport_tutorial:cmake /home/paris/catkin_ws/logs/image_transport_tutorial/build.cmake.log
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/assert.cmake:17 (message):
Assertion failed: check for file existence, but filename
(RT_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND) unset.  Message: RT Library

Call stack(most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/tools/rt.cmake:42 (assert_file_exists)
    /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/old.cmake :147(include)
    /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake :20(include)
    Cmakelists.txt: 4 (find_package)
```

Before, if the code in src file don't include the image_transport related libraries, I can run $catkin build without any error.

Wonder that what will cause this problem because I can't find any solution in the internet.Tks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267706/assertion-failed:-check-for-file-existence/) by [CTYang](https://answers.ros.org/users/31388/ctyang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Cmake is detecting that you're missing the RT_LIBRARY which is expected to be installed on your system.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0